# [[object HTMLUListElement]] while loading custom UI in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I was trying to load a tree view inside div element of tabular type in Angular JS, but it is not loading the tree view instead it is showing a message as "[[object HTMLUListElement]]" in the UI with no error.

Below is the code for custom tree view:

```
companyMapControllers.directive("treeModel", ['$compile',function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function(a, g, c) {
                var e = c.treeModel,
                    h = c.nodeLabel || "label",
                    d = c.nodeChildren || "children",
                    k = '<ul><li data-ng-repeat="node in ' + e + '"><i class="collapsed" data-ng-show="node.' + d + '.length && node.collapsed" data-ng-click="selectNodeHead(node, $event)"></i><i class="expanded" data-ng-show="node.' + d + '.length && !node.collapsed" data-ng-click="selectNodeHead(node, $event)"></i><i class="normal" data-ng-hide="node.' +
                    d + '.length"></i> <span data-ng-class="node.selected" data-ng-click="selectNodeLabel(node, $event)">{{node.' + h + '}}</span><div data-ng-hide="node.collapsed" data-tree-model="node.' + d + '" data-node-id=' + (c.nodeId || "id") + " data-node-label=" + h + " data-node-children=" + d + "></div></li></ul>";
                e && e.length && (c.angularTreeview ? (a.$watch(e, function(m, b) {
                    g.empty().html($compile(k)(a))
                }, !1), a.selectNodeHead = a.selectNodeHead || function(a, b) {
                    b.stopPropagation && b.stopPropagation();
                    b.preventDefault && b.preventDefault();
                    b.cancelBubble = !0;
                    b.returnValue = !1;
                    a.collapsed = !a.collapsed
                }, a.selectNodeLabel = a.selectNodeLabel || function(c, b) {
                    b.stopPropagation && b.stopPropagation();
                    b.preventDefault && b.preventDefault();
                    b.cancelBubble = !0;
                    b.returnValue = !1;
                    a.currentNode && a.currentNode.selected && (a.currentNode.selected = void 0);
                    c.selected = "selected";
                    a.currentNode = c
                }) : g.html($compile(k)(a)))
            }
        }
    }])
```

Tabular structure code is as follows :

```
<div>   
    <section>
        <ul ng-init="tab = 1">
            <li ng-class="{active:tab===1}"> 
                <a href ng-click="tab = 1">Solutions</a>    
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab===2}"> 
                <a href ng-click="tab = 2">Company Map</a> 
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab===3}"> 
                <a href ng-click="tab = 3">Services</a> 
            </li>
            <br><br>
            <p ng-show="tab === 1"> Solutions tab </p>
            <div ng-show="tab === 2">
                    <div
                        data-angular-treeview="true"
                        data-tree-model="roleList"
                        data-node-id="roleId"
                        data-node-label="roleName"
                        data-node-children="children" >
                    </div>              
            </div>      
            <p ng-show="tab === 3"> Services provided are displayed here </p>
        </ul>       
    </section>  
</div>
```

My CSS is :

```
p {
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
        color: rgb(62, 62, 62);
        margin: 18px;
    }
    ul {
        float: left;
        height: 500px;
        width: 700px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: solid 1px rgb(198, 198, 198);
        padding: 7px 11px;
        background-color: rgb(248,248,248);
    }
    li {
        float: left;
        width: 175px;
        background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
        padding: 5px 19px;
        margin: 5px 2px 5px 0px;
        color: black;
        list-style: none;
    }
    li:hover, li:hover a {
        background-color: rgb(6,179,6);
        color:white;
    }
    li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 21px;
        font-style: italic;
        text-shadow: 1px 0px 3px rgb(157, 157, 157);
    }
    li:nth-child(1) { border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px; margin-left: 1px;}
    li:nth-child(3) { border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;}
    .active {
        background-color: rgb(6,179,6);
    }
div[data-angular-treeview] {
  /* prevent user selection */
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

  /* default */
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size:13px;
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div[data-tree-model] ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none; 
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div[data-tree-model] li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

div[data-tree-model] li .expanded {
  padding: 1px 10px;
  background-image: "-";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div[data-tree-model] li .collapsed {
  padding: 1px 10px;
  background-image: "+";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div[data-tree-model] li .normal {
  padding: 1px 10px;
  background-image: "+";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div[data-tree-model] li i, div[data-tree-model] li span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div[data-tree-model] li .selected {
  background-color: #aaddff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}
```

Data is as follows :

```
[
{
    "roleName": "Function1", "roleId":"role1",
    "children": [{"roleName":"Department1","roleId":"role11","children":[{"roleName":"Employee1","roleId":"role111"},{"roleName":"Employee2","roleId":"role112"}]},
                {"roleName":"Department2","roleId":"role12","children":[{"roleName":"Employee3","roleId":"role121"},{"roleName":"Employee4","roleId":"role122"}]}]
},
{
    "roleName": "Function2", "roleId":"role2",
    "children": [{"roleName":"Department3","roleId":"role21","children":[{"roleName":"Employee1","roleId":"role211"},{"roleName":"Employee2","roleId":"role212"}]},
                {"roleName":"Department4","roleId":"role22","children":[{"roleName":"Employee3","roleId":"role221"},{"roleName":"Employee4","roleId":"role222"}]}]
},
{
    "roleName": "Function3", "roleId":"role3",
    "children": [{"roleName":"Department5","roleId":"role31","children":[{"roleName":"Employee1","roleId":"role311"},{"roleName":"Employee2","roleId":"role312"}]},
                {"roleName":"Department6","roleId":"role32","children":[{"roleName":"Employee3","roleId":"role321"},{"roleName":"Employee4","roleId":"role322"}]}]
}
```

]

Comment: facing the same issue, how you corrected it. I'm also getting [[object HTMLUILstElement]] and I have done all the setup as mentioned .

Answer (score 0):

You are using `'<ul><li data-ng-repeat="node in ' + e + '">`, which calls `e.toString()`, which gives you `[[object HTMLUListElement]]`.

You need something like this:

`a.nodes = c.treeModel;
k = '<ul><li data-ng-repeat="node in nodes">...`

Comment: I tried this solution but did not found any change in the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution

```
App.controller('MainMenuController', [ '$scope', 'DataService', '$location',
    '$compile', function($scope, DataService, $location, $compile) {
        var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#myDiv'));
        myEl.append(DataService.valueObject);
        $compile(myEl)($scope);
    } ]);
```

Compiling will work.

Comment: Could you please include an explanation, what your code exactly does and why you did it like you did in your answer?